# Filter resource via Maven generated by Java annotation Processor

Tags: java, maven

I have an annotation processor that is generating a text file to be included in the compiled jar. (The annotation processor is in the same project that is being compiled).

The generated file has a `${project.version}` String in it that I wish to be replaced as typical maven resource filtering would do.

How do I achieve this?

My current pom.xml's build section is

```
<build>
    <finalName>prodity-commons-spigot</finalName>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>

    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/META-INF</directory>
            <targetPath>./META-INF</targetPath>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-compile</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile-project</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

**filtering** must be true :

```
<resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/META-INF</directory>
            <targetPath>./META-INF</targetPath>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

Comment: I set filtering to true however it does not filter the file that I am creating the file via the ProcessingEnvironment's Filer

Comment: then you should copy your file using maven-assembly with filtering true